# Hugo shortcode adding extra space at end of link text

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm using a Hugo shortcode to add a class to links. We want to copy Wikipedia's style for "red links", pages that haven't been built yet but are planned.

The shortcode red-link.html looks like this:

```
<a href="{{ .Get "url" }}" class="red-link">{{ with .Get "title" }}{{.}}{{else}}{{.Get "url"}}{{end}}</a>
```

When I use it in a markdown file, it looks like this:

```
Here is an {{< red-link title="example red link" url="#" >}}.
```

What I *want* is this (no space between link text and punctuation):

```
<p>Here is an <a href="#" class="red-link">example red link</a>.</p>
```

What I get is this:

```
<p>
    "Here is an "
    <a href="#" class="red-link">example red link</a>
    " ."
</p>
```

Which ends up looking like this:

[image: Screenshot of the stupid error I can't fix]

What do I need to change to remove that extra space between the end of the link and the period?

Comment: "Which ends up looking like this:" Seems to be blank, do you mind checking and fixing that? But your answer is probably: https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/#whitespace

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue but the project was configured to add a **new line at the end of all files**. Instead of reconfiguring the project to also allow files without new lines at the end, I have found an ugly, but working solution.

Given the example of catertot, you probably have the following shotcode (notice the ending new line):

```
<a href="{{ .Get "url" }}" class="red-link">{{ blabla }}</a>
```

The solution is to add a `{{- "" -}}` at the very end of the shortcode:

```
<a href="{{ .Get "url" }}" class="red-link">{{ blabla }}</a>{{- "" -}}
```

This tells Hugo to strip any whitespace behind the link itself, resulting in a perfectly inlined shortcode without spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I use a Hugo theme for my website which had a custom shortcode **render-link.html** file in `quickstart/themes/YOUR_THEME/layouts/_default/_markup` by default. The solution, as another answer points out is to add whitespace delimiters `{{- /* This comment removes trailing newlines. */ -}}` to your file, which removes leading and trailing whitespaces. However, in my theme, this was placed after the `</a>` tag, rendering it useless (see below).

```
<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL -}}"{{ with .Title -}} title="{{ . -}}"{{ end -}}{{ if strings.HasPrefix .Destination "http" -}} target="_blank"{{ end -}}>{{ .Text -}}</a>{{- "" -}}
```

Ensure your shortcode looks as follows:

```
<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL -}}"{{ with .Title -}} title="{{ . -}}"{{ end -}}{{ if strings.HasPrefix .Destination "http" -}} target="_blank"{{ end -}}>{{ .Text -}}{{- "" -}}</a>
```

If this does not solve the problem, consider checking your IDE settings. For example, in VS Code, you should consider disabling `Settings → Files: Insert Final Newline`.

Check out these other threads:

- [Single whitespace character after custom link template for Goldmark #6832](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/6832)
- [Markdown render hooks extra space](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/markdown-render-hooks-extra-space/27446/1)

Comment: Thank you, I use exactly the same shortcode and you have improved my own theme.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a custom `render-link.html` file containing an empty line, this was creating a new paragraph before each link included with a Shortcode.

**Removing this empty line in `render-link.html`** fixed my issue. To be clear:

Before:

```
<!-- Source: https://roneo.org/en/hugo-open-external-links-in-a-new-tab/ -->

<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}"{{ with .Title}} title="{{ . }}"{{ end }}{{ if strings.HasPrefix .Destination "http" }} target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" {{ end }}>{{ .Text  | safeHTML }}</a>
```

After:

```
<!-- Source: https://roneo.org/en/hugo-open-external-links-in-a-new-tab/ -->
<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}"{{ with .Title}} title="{{ . }}"{{ end }}{{ if strings.HasPrefix .Destination "http" }} target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" {{ end }}>{{ .Text  | safeHTML }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your shortcode file, remove everything, including all blank lines, below this:

```
<a href="{{ .Get "url" }}" class="red-link">{{ with .Get "title" }}{{.}}{{else}}{{.Get "url"}}{{end}}</a>
```

If that doesn't get rid of that space, try using appropriate
[Go Template trim-whitespace delimiters](https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/#whitespace) (`{{-`  and  `-}}`). For example, try changing the above to this:

```
<a href="{{ .Get "url" -}}" class="red-link">{{ with .Get "title" -}}{{. -}}{{else -}}{{.Get "url" -}}{{end -}}</a>
```

I had this problem with my `years-since` shortcode, which I wrote about at https://www.ii.com/hugo-tips-fragments/#_8_years_since.